# Inside Document Library, some files will open inside the browser (.xlsx & .vsdx), while other (.docx & .txt) will open with the client application

Tags: 2013, document-library, administration, office

I am working on a team site inside SharePoint on-premises 2013. and I have a document library where i set to open the documents in the browser, as follow:-

[image]

Now i uploaded multiple files with different formats such as; `.xlsx` & `.vsdx` &  `.docx` & `.txt` & `.pnp`.

But i have noted the only the Excel(`.xlsx`) and Visio (`.vsdx`) will open in the browser, while the other file formats (`.docx` & `.txt` & `.pnp`) will show a dialog as follow when i click on them:-

[image]

so i am not sure what control this? and is there a way to force all the file types to open in the browser? and edit them directly inside the browser?

Second question. Now even when i open the Excel and the Visio inside the browser, i can not directly edit them and save.. where i have to click on "open in excel" or "open in visio">> then edit them inside the related client application..

so i am a bot confused on what is controlling these behaviors ?

Answer (score 1):

Please install OWA services if you want to Edit or view office files in browsers, If you have excel services you can able to view Excel files but cant edit

Comment: Now i already have a managed service for Excel Services Application + Visio Graphics Service already configured.. but I do not have OWA .. So this mean the Excel Service+ Visio Service will ONLY allow me to view excel sheets and Visio diagrams inside the browser but do not allow me to edit them? second point now if i want OWA inside on-premises this will require additional license ,,, is this correct?

Comment: Yup, U have to install them on different server in your farm

Comment: @johnG I would suggest to open the documents in client applications as opening in web browser restricts lot of the functions like macros. This is a future proof solution